# Doctrine QueryBuilder custom field, constructed from two different

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, concatenation

I've searching for the solution to my problem, I wouldn't call it a problem, but I just can't find any documentation.

Basically what I want to do is:
I have two entities: **Gallery & PhotoItem**

**PhotoItem** has these fields: *id, image, updatedAt*

*image* field holds the name of the photo item with its extension.

When I get certain Gallery with joins to PhotoItem. I would also like to get additional field, which would be a CONCAT of %certain.parameter.with.baseurl.of.website% and the *image* field. So my API would return full path to the asset.

**Is it possible to do it in QueryBuilder?** Because right now I would loop through elements in PHP and add additional property.

Comment: why would you do that in in query? aren't you using ORM (because if you do just create an additional getter in your PhotoItem Entity)?

Comment: That's what I thought to do. I actually did this but since the project has flawed design when building API, I couldn't do these things. I'll rewrite the code then. Thanks.